Py в exe при помощи Pyinstaller exe файлом
Пишу приложение которое должно уметь формировать exe файлы из скриптов на python. Вот код установщика:
import PyInstaller.__main__
PyInstaller.__main__.run(['-n=Другой файл', '-F', '--icon=Icon.ico', 'Test.py'])

При запуске данного кода, как python-скрипт, данный код работает корректно. Однако если создать exe файл из данного файла с помощью PyInstaller, PyInstaller уходит в бесконечный цикл, повторяя одно и то же сообщение, не формируя из py скрипта exe файл:
250 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.10.0, contrib hooks: 2024.8
250 INFO: Python: 3.12.6
273 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
273 INFO: Python environment: C:\Users\219D8C~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI116882
273 INFO: wrote D:\PC projects\PROGRAMM\Test.spec
276 INFO: Module search paths (PYTHONPATH):
['C:\\Users\\219D8C~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI116882\\base_library.zip',
'C:\\Users\\219D8C~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI116882\\lib-dynload',
'C:\\Users\\219D8C~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI116882',
'C:\\Users\\219D8C~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI116882\\setuptools\\_vendor',
'D:\\PC projects\\PROGRAMM']

При закрытии этого исполняемого файла появляется столько KeyboardInterrupt, сколько исполняемый файл успел продублировать это сообщение. Пытался скопировать весь модуль PyInstaller в установщик при помощи флагов --collect-all, --recursive-copy-metadata, но это тоже ни к чему не привело. Близкая проблема тут
Возможно, есть способ изменить иконку уже существующего exe файла средствами python? Тот скрипт, который должен получаться - однотипен и постоянен. Просто нужна возможность установить на него иконку (именно exe файла)

А вы уверены что собрать PyInstaller в exe файл это точно хорошая идея?

dofi4ka, а Вы уверены, что программы типа portable - плохая идея? Представьте себе, многие программисты пишут не только себе, но и другим, да ещё на расстоянии. Устанавливать где-то, кому-то Питон НЕобязательно. Для этого и существуют автономные сборки, которые прекрасно работают.

Если же всё-таки вам никак не обойтись без данной фичи, то вот способ:
В вашу программу в какую-нибудь папку запихиваем интерпретатор Python (все файлы) с установленными модулями (к примеру, python), далее можем создать сценарий windows pyinstaller.bat, в нём пишем следующий код:
python\python.exe -m PyInstaller %*

Теперь мы можем запустить компиляцию из скрипта py с помощью команды
reg = f'pyinstaller -F --icon="{self.settings.value(self._project)}" -n="{self.fw.data["out"]}" --clean ARTmain.py'
os.system(reg)

Это просто пример, запрос может быть любым. Притом это будет работать, даже если мы переведём скрипт в exe файл, ведь мы просто запускаем формирование exe на вшитом интерпретаторе python.

Не знаю, откуда Вы взяли такую заумную писанину, я такой даже на официальном сайте не видел. Попрощайтесь с ней и поскорее.
Вот страница документации: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/
Вот пример сборки, которую использую я сам (это команда из файла .cmd; если не поймёте что за опции, спрашивайте, я уточню):
pyinstaller -y --uac-admin --clean ^
--onedir --runtime-tmpdir="." --distpath="." --contents-directory="Runtimes" ^
--add-data=".\DB\rhymes.db;DB" ^
--add-data=".\HELP\rhymes.pdf;HELP" ^
--hide-console=hide-early --icon=..\IMAGES\app.png .\rhymes.py


Получается, это сценарий командной строки. Для автономного создания exe файла, получается, необходимо вшить в программу интерпретатор с библиотекой PyInstaller (ну и парой других, скорее всего) и уже из кода запускать данный сценарий?

До кода установщика додумался сам, анализируя исходники PyInstaller. Позже увидел этот же самый способ на сайте с документацией: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-from-python-code

Скажите, почему такую простую вещь надо обязательно доводить до космической сложности? Я же написал Вам. Это команда в командном файле - .bat или .cmd. Написали программу на Питоне? Потестировали? Работает? Запустили .bat или .cmd и получили автономную сборку. Я ж намекал, забудьте о своей вот этой "технологии" и поскорее. Кого куда вшить? Какие интерпретаторы? Какая пара других? Какой сценарий? В этой команде не на что смотреть.

Так в том то и дело, что ГОТОВАЯ ПРОГРАММА ДОЛЖНА САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО ФОРМИРОВАТЬ EXE, на компьютере пользователя, у которого, возможно, не будет питона

Ну, если Вы до всего додумались сами, почему оказались здесь с нерабочим вариантом? Я работаю с pyinstaller давно и сплю, когда собираю очередную сборку. На том сайте много чего написано. Но не всё ж надо воспринимать как работающее и подходящее. Я написал пример РАБОЧЕГО ВАРИАНТА. И главное, если Ваш скрипт работает автономно,  то есть путём запуска главного скрипта .py из ОС, сборка тоже будет рабочая (я пока не видел исключений).

Готовая программа должна сама? Рекомендую пересмотреть идеи. Перемудрили. Без этого можно и нужно обойтись - уверен практически на 100%. Если Вас так заботит этот потенциально стрёмный вариант, значит, у Вас много времени на игры.

Я уже молчу о том, что на компе пользователя должен быть корректно установлен Питон, все модули, все версии всего должны соответствовать. И зачем тогда вообще нужен автономный вариант, если у пользователя на компе надо устанавливать Питон и все модули?! Если Вы желаете просто спрятать код от пользователя, достаточно просто сформировать из .py его исполняемый вариант .pyc.
